# change the jtree node text runtime

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to create a JTree in java swing now i want to change the node text at runtime

```
try
 {

int a=1,b=2,c=3;
 DefaultMutableTreeNode root =
new DefaultMutableTreeNode("A"+a);
DefaultMutableTreeNode child[]=new DefaultMutableTreeNode[1];
DefaultMutableTreeNode grandChild[]= new DefaultMutableTreeNode[1];

child[0] = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Central Excise"+b);
  grandChild[0]=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("CE Acts: "+c);
child[0].add(grandChild[0]);
 root.add(child[0]);
tree = new JTree(root);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)

 {
  ex.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Now i want later on how can i change  A 1 to a 2 dynamically and similarly in child and grand child nodes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [`javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.setUserObject(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#setUserObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
root.setUserObject("My label");
model.nodeChanged(root);
```

This assumes that you are using the `DefautltTreeModel`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a custom TreeModel, then the model of your tree is a [DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html).

You'll need to walk the tree with *some kind of comparator*, given your  *DefaultMutableTreeNode*  ***getUserObject()*** (string or whatever) to achieve what you want.

You have 2 *simple* options accordingly to your question and the code that you pasted :

- If your change is triggered by let's say a click event, you can get the selection and walk the tree from there.
- Otherwise you'll need to walk the tree from the root

Upon successful changes, you'll need to fire events from the model that will trigger later a repaint of the view (*nodesWereInserted*, etc.).

Hope it helps